# My Long text of Autocompletetextview appeasr completely on the screen

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

What I need is that when a user types characters, it should show suggestions, and that suggestion has to be displayed completely on the screen. Display the text complete or that the long text of my string appears continuously in the second line of the autocomplete

```
package com.example.epson.buscadormep;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] values = new String[]{"Cilindros pequeños de oxigeno gaseoso o de aire, de uso medicinal", "Dispositivos que contienen oxigeno liquido",
                "Cilindo de un gas de la dicivion 2.2 para activar las extremidades artiiciales mecanicas", "Articulos medicinales no radiactivos (incluso aerosoles)"};
        //final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,values);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,values);
        final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMercancias);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);//will start working from second character
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter); //setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView

        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
                //This will give you the string value of selected list item
                //TextView listItem = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
                //You can do this or apply own logic to find the selected value case


                if (autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Cilindros pequeños de oxigeno gaseoso o de aire, de uso medicinal"))
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent( MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                }
                if (autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Dispositivos que contienen oxigeno liquido"))
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent( MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class));
                }
                if (autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Cilindo de un gas de la dicivion 2.2 para activar las extremidades artiiciales mecanicas"))
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent( MainActivity.this, Main4Activity.class));
                }
                if (autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Articulos medicinales no radiactivos (incluso aerosoles)"))
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent( MainActivity.this, Main5Activity.class));
                };
            }
        });



    }
}
```

And this is my activity_main.xml...I think that I have to fix this or not?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mercancias Peligrosas: "
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMercancias"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="Escriba mercancias peligrosa"

        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a custom layout for the adapter that you set for the autoCompleteTextView:

MainActivity.java

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_autocomplete_item,R.id.autoCompleteItem, values);
```

custom_autocomplete_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```